# How to set streaming app checkpointing to Azure storage?

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying set checkpointing for spark streaming application to Azure storage. I was using S3 and the code was working fine.

Here is the latest code of how I set checkpointing to Azure.

```scala
sc.hadoopConfiguration
      .set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration
      .set(
        "fs.azure.account.key.[name].blob.core.windows.net",
        [key]
      )
    ssc.checkpoint(
      "https://[name].blob.core.windows.net/[blob]")
```

Here is the error message that I am getting when starting.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#access-azure-blob-storage-directly) - it's for databricks but should still apply.

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory-name>")
```

==> So, use `wasbs` instead of `https`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs

Comment: This is the new error that I am getting after changing `https` to `wasbs`.